# Summary of $\frac{dM(t)}{M(t)}$ using Ito's formula in dimension $d$

Tags: stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations, stochastic-pde

**EDIT:** This question has been solved!

Consider a $d$-dimensional Brownian motion $W$ and the stochastic differential equation(s)

$$
\begin{align}
dX&=b(X)dt+\rho(X)dW\\
X_0&=x,
\end{align}
$$

where $\rho(X)\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ and $b(X)\in\mathbb{R}^d$. Moreover we have

$$
\begin{align}
a(X)=\rho(X)\rho(X)^\top&=a+\sum_{i=1}^d \alpha_i X_i\\
b(X)&=b+\sum_{i=1}^d \beta_i X_i,
\end{align}$$

where $a,\alpha_i$ are $d\times d$-matrices and $b, \beta_i$ $d$-vectors.

Further there is a $\mathbb{C}$-valued function $\phi$ and a $\mathbb{C}^d$-valued function $\psi=(\psi_1,\ldots,\psi_d)^\top$, which solve the Riccati equations

$$
\begin{align}
\partial_t\phi(t,u)&=\frac{1}{2}\psi(t,u)^\top a\ \psi(t,u)+ b^\top \psi(t,u) \\
\phi(0,u)&=0\\
\partial_t\psi_i(t,u)&=\frac{1}{2}\psi(t,u)^\top \alpha_i\ \psi(t,u)+ \beta_i^\top \psi(t,u)\\
\psi(0,u)&=u
\end{align}
$$

For $T>0$ and $u \in \mathrm{i} \mathbb{R}^{d}$ define the complex-valued Itô process
$$
M_t=\mathrm{e}^{\phi(T-t, u)+\psi(T-t, u)^{\top} X_t}
$$

> Now, the author states, that we find
> $$
> \frac{d M_t}{M_t}=I_t d t+\psi(T-t, u)^{\top} \rho(X_t) d W_t
> $$
> with
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> I_t=&-\partial_{T} \phi(T-t, u)-\partial_{T} \psi(T-t, u)^{\top} X_t \\
> &+\psi(T-t, u)^{\top} b(X_t)+\frac{1}{2} \psi(T-t, u)^{\top} a(X_t) \psi(T-t, u)
> \end{aligned}
> $$
>
> by applying Ito's formula to the real and complex part.

**My question:** How did the author come up with exactly this $I_t$? Unfortunately I cannot find precisely this $I_t$.

**My attempt:** Let's try this for $d=1$:

$$f(z):=\mathrm{e}^{\phi(T-t, u)+\psi(T-t, u) z}$$

Applying Ito's formula, I find

$$
\begin{align}
M_t=\mathrm{e}^{\phi(T-t, u)+\psi(T-t, u) X_t}=f(X_t)&=f(X_0)+\int_0^t f'(X_s) dX_s+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t f''(X_s) \langle X\rangle_s\\
&=f(X_0)+\int_0^t \psi(T-s, u)M_sd(b(X)dt+\rho(X)dW)_s\\
&\quad + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \psi(T-s, u)^2M_sd\langle b(X)dt+\rho(X)dW\rangle_s\\
&=f(X_0)+\int_0^t \psi(T-s, u)b(X_s)M_sds\\
&\quad + \int_0^t \psi(T-s, u)\rho(X_s)M_sdW_s\\
&\quad + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \psi(T-s, u)^2\rho(X_s)^2M_sds\\
\end{align}$$

In this case

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d M_t}{M_t}&= \Big(\psi(T-t, u)b(X_t) + \frac{1}{2} \psi(T-t, u)^2\rho(X_t)^2\Big)d t\\ &\quad +\psi(T-t, u) \rho(X_t) d W_t\\
&= \Big(\psi(T-t, u)b(X_t) + \frac{1}{2} \psi(T-t, u)\rho(X_t)\rho(X_t)^\top \psi(T-t, u)\Big)d t\\ &\quad +\psi(T-t, u) \rho(X_t) d W_t\\
&= \Big(\psi(T-t, u)b(X_t) + \frac{1}{2} \psi(T-t, u) a(X_t) \psi(T-t, u)\Big)d t\\ &\quad +\psi(T-t, u) \rho(X_t) d W_t
\end{align}$$

And therefore

$$I_t = \psi(T-t, u)b(X_t) + \frac{1}{2} \psi(T-t, u) a(X_t) \psi(T-t, u)$$

**Final thoughts:** It seems, that I am missing these partial derivatives with respect to $T$. Was my definition of $f$ wrong? Should I have defined

$$f(t,z):=\mathrm{e}^{\phi(T-t, u)+\psi(T-t, u) z}$$

and apply the multi dimensional Ito formula? Maybe these derivates would come from there? Also, I would be curious how to do the calculation in the actual dimension $d\ne 1$.

I'd be very thankful for any hint or help on these questions. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Ok, I think now I see it, since $\partial_t \phi(T-t,u)=-\partial_t \phi(T-t,u)$, this gives the minus sign using the Ito formula for Ito processes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itô%27s_lemma#Mathematical_formulation_of_Itô's_lemma The second derivative with respect to $t$ "vanishes", because this would only occur in the covariation of $[t,X_t]$, $[X_t, t]$ or $[t,t]$ which all are equal to $0$.

Comment: In the end one has to consider $f(t,z_1,\ldots,z_d)$ and apply Ito's formula for higher dimensions. However, the term $\psi^\top a(X) \psi$ does not seem right so far, because it would imply $[X_i,X_j]=id$, which is not possible considering Levy's characterization. I think it should be $\frac{1}{2}\langle \psi^2,\rho^2\rangle$. I hope these two coincide somehow in the end... (with $\psi^2=(\psi_1^2,\ldots,\psi_d^2)$ ...)

Comment: Ok, this problem has been resolved, too, since $X_j=\int b_j(X_s)ds+\sum_{i=1}^d\int\rho_{ji}(X_s)d(W_i)_s$. I might write an answer later.

Comment: Actually, it's $\partial_t\phi(T-t,u)=-\partial_1\phi(T-t,u)$ the derivative of the first variable, you can also write this as $\partial_T$.

Comment: This is way beyond my "paygrade" (lol) but isn't using the same letter "d" for both dimensions and the differential operator a bad idea?

Comment: True. However, I‘ve seen a lot of authors using $d$ for the dimension. I guess once you start running out of variables you give them multiple definitions, in which they do not interfere so much as they would in other places? :-)